# How do you convert an xcode project into a cocoapod?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I have a piece of code that I find I am reusing in multiple different projects so I'd like to make it a cocoapod and use a private cocoapod repo.

My question is How do I setup an xcode project to be a cocoapod?  Should it be a static library or an empty 'project' with an appdelegate ok?  It seems that you would not want an appdelegate or a main.m in your pod, but it sure makes it easier to run and debug.

Thanks

Comment: Why wan't you make it a CocoaPod? IMHO, including that "piece of code" as an Xcode subproject whose product is a library or framework is always the better approach.

Comment: Cocoa pods will allow you to better manage your dependencies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A CocoaPod can be as simple as a couple of files. It's all in how you define it in your podspec. You only include the relevant source code files in your podspec (no `main.m` or anything unless you have a really good reason to do so). My recommendation would be to have a `Source` directory in the top-level of your repo containing the relevant source files.

If you want to have a demo project to show how to use it, you can do that on the same level, and use the files from the `Source` directory (don't copy them somewhere under the demo project directory). *Having an actual Xcode project is not required to have a pod.*

You would probably have something very close the their demo of a very basic podspec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = 'Reachability'
  s.version      = '3.1.0'
  s.license      =  :type => 'BSD' 
  s.homepage     = 'https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability'
  s.authors      =  'Tony Million' => 'tonymillion@gmail.com' 
  s.summary      = 'ARC and GCD Compatible Reachability Class for iOS and OS X. Drop in replacement for Apple Reachability.'
  s.source       =  :git => 'https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability.git', :tag => 'v3.1.0' 
  s.source_files = 'Reachability.h,m'
  s.framework    = 'SystemConfiguration'
  s.requires_arc = true
end
```

Source: http://docs.cocoapods.org/specification.html

And here is the repo for Reachability in this example:
https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability